# Theory level obtain command

Tags: isabelle

In a local proof block in Isabelle I can use the very convenient `obtain` command, which allows me to define a constant with given properties:

```
proof
  ...
  from `∃x. P x ∧ Q x`
  obtain x where "P x" and "Q x" by blast
  ...
```

What is the most convenient way to do that on the theory or locale level?

I can do it by hand using `SOME`, but it seems to be unnecessary complicated:

```
lemma ex: "∃x. P x ∧ Q x"
  sorry

definition x where "x = (SOME x. P x ∧ Q x)"
lemma P_x: "P x" and Q_x: "Q x"
  unfolding atomize_conj x_def by (rule someI_ex, rule ex)
```

Another, more direct, way seems to be `specification`:

```
consts x :: nat
specification (x) P_x: "P x"  Q_x: "Q x" by (rule ex)
```

but it requires the somewhat low-level `consts` command, and worse, it does not work in a local context.

Would it be possible to have something as nice as the `obtain` command on the theory level?

Comment: The command `specification` is precisely what you are looking for. It just has not yet been localised like all the other theory commands. If you have some time, feel free to attempt to localise it.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to the `specification` command - I really could have used this in my Akra–Bazzi AFP entry. Unfortunately, I need it inside a locale.

Comment: @AndreasLochbihler, do you want to turn that into an answer?